# I want to import obj files in blender

Tags: python, import, blender, modeling, .obj

Right now my code is as follow:

```
import os
import bpy

path_to_objdir = os.path.join('C:\\','Users\vincent.martel\Documents\Data\full_mesh')
file_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_objdir))
obj_list = [item for item in file_list if item.endswith('.obj')]
for item in obj_list:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(path_to_objdir, item)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath = path_to_file, split_mode = "OFF")
```

When I run this code, the console outputs an error and highlights the line where I initialize my file_list but does not say anything else (blender console does not even name the error).

Can anyone find a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out the value of your variable `path_to_objdir` and copy/paste it into a `dir` statement at the Windows console. Does it work? If not, then fix the value so that it does work. I don't have your system so I can't verify this, but the first thing I would try is

```
path_to_objdir = os.path.join('C:','Users','vincent.martel','Documents','Data','full_mesh')
```

Comment: That's the thing I copied the exact path in my research folder

Comment: Well, if you did it, it won't work inside a Python string, because (for example) `Data\full_mesh` does not mean what you pasted in, but `Data<formfeed>ull_mesh`. That is because `\f` has a special meaning in a Pyton string. I suppose I don't need to explain that you can't have a formfeed character in a Windows filename. Either use `os.path.join` as shown in the response, or, if you want to put an entire Windows path in a Python string literal, use a raw string: r'Users\vincent.martel\Documents\Data\full_mesh'